# BACnet or KNX comparison with RabbitMQ or Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq, bacnet, knx

I would like to see how BACnet and KNX functionalities in a lighting control system can be comparable with a lighting control system created using Kafka or RabbitMQ frameworks. I want to find the pro and cons of implementing a lighting control system with BACnet or KNX or Kafka or RabbitMQ. But it seems that I am trying to compare apples with oranges.

Does it make sense to compare BACnet and KNX functionalities with RabbitMQ and Kafka applications? Or makes it more sense to compare BACnet and KNX protocol with MQTT or IP?

Answer (score 0):

At least where BACnet is concerned, it's goal is the device-agnostic/romantic-poet view of the world (- visually & comically, only romantic-poet in contrast to the old world order of drug-dealer like vendor's trying to hook you solely upon their proprietary rendition of the building-controls world  :P  ;D), so it's trying to solve a business problem (with technology), and not focus immediately upon the technological facet such as using queues (aka RabbitMQ for example).

I think overall, it would be fair to say that your probably comparing two building-controls protocols versus two technologies that you at some level use to integrate with (or even use as part of implementing) a building-controls system (/related system).